# Failure writing to log file with RavenDB Embedded on Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, ravendb, azure-web-app-service

I am running an MVC web site on Windows Azure and using RavenDB embedded. If the web site is "cold" (unloaded from the Azure instance), I get the following error message on the first hit to the web site:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Failure writing to log file
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentLogWriteFailException: Failure
>   writing to log file
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [EsentLogWriteFailException: Failure writing to log file]
>   Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.Check(Int32 err) +21
>   Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.JetInit(JET_INSTANCE& instance) +23
>   Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Initialize(IUuidGenerator
>   uuidGenerator, OrderedPartCollection`1 documentCodecs) +309
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Could not open transactional storage:
>   C:\DWASFiles\Sites\reflix\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Data]
>   Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Initialize(IUuidGenerator
>   uuidGenerator, OrderedPartCollection`1 documentCodecs) +443
>   Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase..ctor(InMemoryRavenConfiguration
>   configuration) +994
>   Raven.Client.Embedded.EmbeddableDocumentStore.InitializeInternal()
>   +313    Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore.Initialize() +463    Reflix.MvcApplication.InitializeRavenDB(String dataDirectory, Boolean
>   rethrowException) +135    Reflix.MvcApplication.Application_Start()
>   +131
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not open transactional storage:
>   C:\DWASFiles\Sites\reflix\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Data]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +9859441
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +336
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not open transactional storage:
>   C:\DWASFiles\Sites\reflix\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Data]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9873784 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18033

If I wait a minute or two, the web site comes up fine. So clearly this is a first-start issue. Anyone have any ideas how to resolve the problem?

My configuration:

- MVC 4
- .NET 4.5
- RavenDB 2.0.2360

---

**Update:** The Azure team is looking at this as a possible defect with the Azure Websites. More updates as soon as I hear anything.

Comment: Are you using **Azure Websites** or **Azure Web Role**?

Comment: Plus one for this question, Experience the same problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was confirmed as a bug in Azure Websites, which has now been rolled out. I don't have any additional details, but the site now works (8/30/2013) and I have made no structural changes to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the event log, it will give you more info.
It looks like *something* is prevent proper write to the logs, check permissions, in particular, you may have CREATE_FILE permission, but not WRITE permission

Comment: Follow up question: how does one view the logs when running in embedded mode?

Comment: I mean, I know there is a `logs` folder, but the only thing in there are some binary `RVN.log` files and some `jrs` files that don't appear to be readable in a text editor. Do I have to d/l them to a local server and copy to the `logs` folder?